# How to Replace special Character in Unix Command

Tags: sed

My source data contains special characters not in readable format. Can anyone help on the below :

[Source data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY3ZC.png)

[image: ascii values]

Commands Tryed:
sed 's/../t/g' test.txt > test2.txt

Answer (score 1):

you can use `tr` to keep only printable characters:

```
tr -cd "[:print:]" <test.txt > test2.txt
```

Uses `tr` delete option on non-printable (print criteria negated by `-c` option)

If you want to *replace* those special chars by something else (ex: X):

```
tr -c "[:print:]" "X" <test.txt > test2.txt
```

With `sed`, you could try that to replace non-printable by `X`:

```
sed -r 's/[^[:print:]]/X/g' text.txt > test2.txt
```

it works on some but fails on chars >127 (maybe because the one I tried is printable as ▒ !) on my machine whereas `tr` works perfectly.

inline examples (printf to generate special chars + filter + od to show bytes):

```
$ printf "\x01ABC\x05\xff\xe0" | od -c
0000000 001   A   B   C 005 377 340
0000007

$ printf "\x01ABC\x05\xff\xe0" | sed "s/[^[:print:]]//g" | od -c
0000000   A   B   C 377 340
0000005

$ printf "\x01ABC\x05\xff\xe0" | tr -cd "[:print:]" | od -c
0000000   A   B   C
0000003
```